# onclick open component page using jquery - Joomla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla

I want to open a page of component 'index.php?option..' using jquery in the same page:

jquery:

```
jQuery("#btnclickme").click(function(){
    jQuery("#divpro").load("index.php?ption=com_hello&view=hello&layout=hello&Itemid");
    });
```

php:

```
$link = 'index.php?ption=com_hello&view=hello&layout=hello&Itemid;
```

html:

```
<a href="<?php echo $link?>" id="btnclickme" name="btnclickme" />
<div id="divpro"></div>
```

Comment: So, what's happening, and what do you expect / want to happen?
It's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I assume he's meant to be loading in data from the URL into `#divpro` via. jQuery's `.load()`. The PHP is most likely not needed in this question, but just out of curiosity, what is the result that is happening now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should prevent the default event of the click event and use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for handling live events.

```
jQuery("#btnclickme").on('click', function(ev) {

    // Don't take the user to the page.
    ev.preventDefault();

    jQuery("#divpro").load("index.php?ption=com_hello&view=hello&layout=hello&Itemid");

    // Just in case.
    return false;

});
```

You can use your browser's developer tools to monitor the web request to see if it's working, and what data is being pulled (if any).

Comment: this is good, but now all the page loaded, i want to only the component page content will be loaded without all the page

Comment: i manage to fix it but now if i want to close this content how can i do it?

Comment: Try adding `&format=raw` to the end of your AJAX url. This will disable all templates, and will only output the content generated from the component.